# Using value outputted by API

Tags: php, api

Bit of a silly question, but im using a solution api that that when i submit the URL it shows me just a number. Im wanting to then use this number on my website as part of another task, but am unsure how to fetch it and display it on my PHP website.

The api also outputs other bits via XML which i can then grab by using the code below. But im not sure how to do so when the value is just displaying on a page rather than in a XML

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("myurl.co.uk") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
?>
```

Comment: So `$xml` is just set to a value?

Comment: Hi @JayBlanchard the xml example was what im using to retrieve from a XML file. However the issue bit im having is when just retrieving the value straight from the webpage. So when i submit my API url, it returns back just a number, and i need to grab that number and echo it on my website if that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP code

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("note.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
//print_r($xml);

echo $xml->to;
echo "<br>";
echo $xml->from; ///and so on
?>
```

**note.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

**EDITED:**
I got your **comment** below, why dont you just use

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Sorry guys but iv probably confused things with my question. I already have this solution for extracting from the XML file - that isnt the issue. The issue is that the API returns the XML on some outputs, but on others it just returns a number within the webpage (not in a XML file). Im trying to grab that number thats just displaying in the webpage on its own.

Comment: why dont you try 
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;

Comment: @Jay. I agree with you Jay. I am new here and I am trying to involve myself in stack overflow. I will keep your suggestion in my mind for my other comments. Thank you Jay Blanchard

Comment: Great, the file_get_contents works a treat. Thanks all